# how to save logging module output in a specified directory in python

Tags: python, logging, save, logfile

By using below mentioned code I am able to save the logging module output in current working directory.

But my aim is to save this  output in some another directory i.e, what ever the directory i mentioned with the file name it has to be save in that directory with the specified file name without changing my current working directory.

```
import logging
LOG_FILENAME = 'example.log'
logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILENAME,level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')
logging.warning('%s before you %s', 'Look', 'leap!')
```

Please can anyone help me to solve this.

Comment: Can you add the log file path in `LOG_FILENAME`? For example: `LOG_FILENAME = '/home/arsho/shovon/Personal_Codes/SO/example.log'`

Comment: Are you getting any error? For instance: `FileNotFoundError` ?

Comment: yes, it's working.  Earlier i checked that several times by changing log_filename, so it didn't create new file for me.if I restart the  kernal and tried with file path it's working.

Comment: is it possible to create more than one log file sequentially in one workspace